# How to integrate SharePoint with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm in the process of setting up a MOSS 2007 (with IIS7 and Server 2008) intranet and am looking to find a way to prevent people from having to log in when they want to view the site.  Ideally, I would like SharePoint to draw from the user's Active Directory account without having to enable guest access.  Can anyone tell me how to do this or have any good resources that describe how to get this done?

Just for the record--I have tried searching Google for the answers but apparently I'm not using the right terms to find what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the url of the site to your user's Local Intranet sites in IE, this will get IE to log in automatically with the current user's credentials.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I played with MOSS, but these two articles should set you on your way.

- [Plan authentication methods (Office SharePoint Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx)
- [How to configure a Windows SharePoint Services virtual server to use Kerberos authentication and how to switch from Kerberos authentication back to NTLM authentication](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832769)

Answer (score 2):

I have found that if the SharePoint box is in the domain, this pretty much happens automatically assuming your client machines are in the domain and are using their domain accounts to logon to Windows.

Comment: This box is in the domain now, but I installed and configured it outside of the domain first when I was doing some testing with it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the application pools to use domain accounts instead of local accounts. When you do that, SharePoint will be aware that it is in a domain.

Comment: But will this prevent user's from having to enter their credentials when they access the site?